# How to extract a specific value from a comma separated string

Tags: jquery

```
var response = [
    [
        "209.90",
        "-3.55",
        "-1.66",
        "50",
        "0",
        "2161",
        "214.20",
        "217.00",
        "207.05",
        "213.45",
        "211.53",
        "169202",
        "357.91",
        "15:44:21"
    ]
];



for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++)
{
    alert(response[i]);
}
```

Is it possible to extract 6th element from the array ??

that is **2161** in the above case ??

http://jsfiddle.net/y9c0m4ny/

Please let me know if this is possible thanks in advance .

Comment: Try `response[0][5]`. I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Are you trying to search for a specific item?

Comment: @soktinpk is right, response[0][5] will work. Also, you will not need for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++) anymore

Comment: That's not a comma separated string. That's an array containing an array of strings.

Answer (score 3):

The response array is an array within an array. So when you `response[0]`, you get the whole array at the index 0. To get the 6th element, that is at the 5th index, you can do `response[0][5]`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an array, which position 0 is an array

```
for(var i=0;i<response[0].length;i++)
{
    alert(response[0][i]);
}
```

To extract 6th element:

```
response[0][5]
```

If you don't want it as a two dimension array, build it with only one bracket:

```
var response = [
    "209.90",
    "-3.55",
    "-1.66",
    "50",
    "0",
    "2161",
    "214.20",
    "217.00",
    "207.05",
    "213.45",
    "211.53",
    "169202",
    "357.91",
    "15:44:21"
];
```

Or, if you can't change this code, use:

```
response = response[0];
```